# PHP Class not being autoloaded by composer or at leas it is not found

Tags: php, composer-php

I am starting a lumen project and I am facing an issue with namespaces and autoload.
In my composer.json file in the project root directory it states the following:

```
   "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
```

In the root dirctory we have the following directory structure (among others):

```
./app/
   ->  Common/TokenFactory.php
   ->  Http/
       ->   Controllers/UserController.php
```

TokenFactory.php contains the following very simple code:

```
<? php
namespace App\Common;

class TokenFactory
{
    public function generateToken($tokenLength = 40)
    {
        $length_div = round($tokenLength/2, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
        return bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length_div));
    }
}

?>
```

I wish to use this class in the UserController.php file where I have the following code:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Common\TokenFactory;

class UserController extends Controller
{
 .............
```

But when I try to instantiate a TokenFactory in the UserController class I get the error:

```
Class 'App\Common\TokenFactory' Not foud.
```

what am I doing wrong? I have created the Common direcotry myself but My undestanding is that Autoloader should be able to use the namespace defines to locate an load the file as needed.
I have been struggling with this for quite some time now, any suggestions will be appreciated.

ADDITIONAL NOTE:
I have noticed that when calling the service, although I get the message that the class was not found, the contents of the file are shown in the error message, meaning that somehow it is locating and loading the file but not recognizing the class when calling it in the file where the use clause is used. See image bellow.[image: ARC Screen Capture]

Comment: Issues with the autoloaders are almost always about the mixed up path or namespaces, so I would double check them first

Comment: Did you regenerate the autoloader using `composer dump-autoload -o`

Comment: yes. I did try regenerating the autoloader using composer dump-autoload -o but it did not make a difference. With regards to @DavidHlavati comment, I have double and tripple checked and can see no issue (although I am not too experienced with namespaces an autoloading) It seems to me it is correclty setup, that Is why I tried describing the path and namespace structure in my original post,

Comment: not sure if this, but namespace App\Http\Controllers; <-- says controllers(notice the 's' at the end). The path is Controller.

Comment: Thanks @DavidHlavati that was a typo on my side. .. i have corrected initial post. Anyway, the problem I am facing is not with the classes in that namespace but with the TokenFactory in the App/Comon namespace

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Is the autoloader used by your application, and does it contain the proper mapping? Does it work if you **remove** the space between `<?`  and `php`  in that `TokenFactory.php`?

Comment: Where is the code that includes the autoloader?

Comment: @gview the code that includes the autoloader is part of the lumen framework that I am using..

Comment: I noticed in the token factory class at the top you have `<? php` and not `<?php`

Comment: Thankyou @gview ...removing that space fixed the issue that has been bugging me for two days :-) Please write this as an answer so I can mark it as correct and you can get the credit. It is amazin how some times really simple issues make you waste so much time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found that in this case a small typo was the culprit.  Unfortunately this happens from time to time.  I will say that command line php does have a syntax checker/linter that can be of aid, if your editor or IDE misses something like this.

```
php -l myscript.php
```

It has helped me out a few times in the past.

In this case the issue was:

```
<? php
namespace App\Common;

class TokenFactory
{
```

The beginning tag needs to be `<?php`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would remove the closing PHP-Tag "?>" at the end of the TokenFactory.

After that I'd suggest to require the TokenFactory-File per hand in your controller: Does it work if you do this?

Comment: I have replaced the use clause by : require(__DIR__.'/../../Common/TokenFactory.php'); and removed the trailing PHP-Tag but the result is exactly the same..